# Me sale el error RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout cuando trato de cargar un RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, recyclerview

estoy haciendo un chat, en donde lo cargo por medio de un RecyclerView. Cuando entro al chat, debería cargar los mensajes, pero no lo hace, y trato de hacer scroll en ese recyclerView y me sale el siguiente mensaje cada vez que hago el scroll:

```
RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

No se que me puede estar causando este error, busque en distintos lados, pero a cada persona tiene una solución diferente.

Este es mi Activity donde esta el chat

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView nombreperfil;
private ImageView imagenperfil;
private RecyclerView mensajes;
private EditText texto;
private Button enviar;
private ImageButton buscarimg;
private CardView globo;
private mensajeAdaptador adaptador;
ArrayList<ModelChat> mensajesArray = new ArrayList<>();
String ruta = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    nombreperfil = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nombreperfil);
    imagenperfil = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagenperfil);
    mensajes = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mensajes);
    texto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.escribir);
    enviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enviar);
    //globo = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardViewMensaje).setForegroundGravity(5);
    buscarimg = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagenbuscar);


    LinearLayoutManager l = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mensajes.setLayoutManager(l);
    mensajes.setAdapter(adaptador);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarchat);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Loperso");
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.heart_full));

    //Cargo los mensajes cuando entra al activity
    ArrayList<Mensaje> listamensajes = new ArrayList<>();
    listamensajes = DAO.cargarMensajes(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < listamensajes.size(); i++) {

        String mnss = listamensajes.get(i).getContenidotexto();
        Date fech = listamensajes.get(i).getFecha();
        String idusuario = listamensajes.get(i).getCedulaUsuario();

        mensajesArray.add(new ModelChat(ModelChat.TEXTO_TYPE, listamensajes.get(i)));
    }
    añadirMensaje();
    //ultimaPos();
    /**adaptador.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
    @Override public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
    super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
    //ultimaPos();
    }
    });**/
    //Cargo los mensajes justo cuando entra al activity


    enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            Mensaje msm = new Mensaje(DAO.obtenerIdACrearMensaje(), String.valueOf(texto.getText()), DAO.obtenerHora(), false, "0", Login.usuario.getCedula(), "0", null);

            //Mensaje que se envia a la base de datos
            DAO.insertarMensaje(msm);
            mensajesArray.add(new ModelChat(ModelChat.TEXTO_TYPE, msm));

            añadirMensaje();
        }
    });


}

public void añadirMensaje() {
    mensajeAdaptador ms = new mensajeAdaptador(mensajesArray, this);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, OrientationHelper.VERTICAL, false);
    mensajes.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mensajes.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mensajes.setAdapter(adaptador);
}}
```

Este es el Adapter de los mensajes. Estoy usando ViewType porque necesito cargar otro Layout en ese mismo recyclerView, ademas de las imágenes que tienen otra estructura diferente.

```
public class mensajeAdaptador extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

private ArrayList<Mensaje> lista =  new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<ModelChat> mDataset;
private int tipomensaje=0;
private int valorCotizacion;
private Context contexto;
private CardView globo;


public mensajeAdaptador(ArrayList<ModelChat> data, Context context) {
    mDataset = new ArrayList<>();
    mDataset = data;
    this.contexto = context;
}


public static class HolderMensaje extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    //Elementos del Mensaje_View
    View mView;
    TextView mensaje;
    TextView hora;
    LinearLayout tarjeta;



    public HolderMensaje(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
            hora = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.horamensaje);
            mensaje = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mensajetexto);
            tarjeta = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layoutmensaje);
    }


    public void colocarDerecha(){
        hora.setGravity(5);
        tarjeta.setGravity(5);
    }

    public void colocarIzquierda(){
        hora.setGravity(3);
        tarjeta.setGravity(3);
    }

    public TextView getMensaje() {
        return mensaje;
    }

    public void setMensaje(TextView mensaje) {
        this.mensaje = mensaje;
    }

    public TextView getHora() {
        return hora;
    }

    public void setHora(TextView hora) {
        this.hora = hora;
    }
}

public static class HolderCotizacion extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView valor;
    TextView hora;

    public HolderCotizacion(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.valor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.valorcotizacion);
        this.hora = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.horamensajecotizacion);

    }
}



@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){

View view;

    switch (viewType){

        case ModelChat.TEXTO_TYPE:{

            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mensaje_view, parent, false);
            return new HolderMensaje(view);
        }
        case ModelChat.COTIZACION_TYPE:{

            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cotizacionmensaje_view, parent, false);
            return new HolderCotizacion(view);
        }
        case ModelChat.IMAGEN_TYPE:{


        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ModelChat object = mDataset.get(position);
    if (object != null) {
        switch (object.type) {
            case ModelChat.TEXTO_TYPE:{

                if (mDataset.get(position).mensaje.getCedulaUsuario().equals(Login.usuario.getCedula())){

                }else{

                }
                HolderMensaje hold = (HolderMensaje) holder;
                hold.mensaje.setText(mDataset.get(position).mensaje.getContenidotexto());
                DateFormat hourFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                hold.hora.setText(String.valueOf(hourFormat.format(mDataset.get(position).mensaje.getFecha())));
            }
            case ModelChat.COTIZACION_TYPE:{
                System.out.println("Entre sin errores");
                //HolderCotizacion hold = (HolderCotizacion) holder;
                //hold.valor.setText("3000");
            }
        }
        }
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    switch (mDataset.get(position).type) {
        case 0:
            return ModelChat.TEXTO_TYPE;
        case 1:
            return ModelChat.IMAGEN_TYPE;
        case 2:
            return ModelChat.COTIZACION_TYPE;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}}
```

Clase Model Chat

```
public class ModelChat {

public static final int TEXTO_TYPE=0;
public static final int IMAGEN_TYPE=1;
public static final int COTIZACION_TYPE=2;

public int type;
public Mensaje mensaje;
public  Cotizacion cotizacion;

public ModelChat(int type, Mensaje mensaje) {
    this.type = type;
    this.mensaje = mensaje;
}

public ModelChat(int type, Cotizacion cotizacion) {
    this.type = type;
    this.cotizacion = cotizacion;
}

public int getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(int type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public Mensaje getMensaje() {
    return mensaje;
}

public void setMensaje(Mensaje mensaje) {
    this.mensaje = mensaje;
}

public Cotizacion getCotizacion() {
    return cotizacion;
}

public void setCotizacion(Cotizacion cotizacion) {
    this.cotizacion = cotizacion;
}}
```

Este es el layout del mensaje de texto

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:id="@+id/layoutmensaje"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="12dp"
android:gravity="left">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewMensaje"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="200dp"
    cardview:cardCornerRadius="10sp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mensajetexto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hola meeen" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/horamensaje"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Horamen" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView></LinearLayout>
```

Y este es el Layout de cotizacion (Va dentro del RecyclerView)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:id="@+id/layoutmensajecotizacion"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="12dp"
android:gravity="left">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewMensaje"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="200dp"
    cardview:cardCornerRadius="10sp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textocotizacionmensaje"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Nueva Cotizacion"
                android:gravity="center"
                />



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/valorcotizacion"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Valor men" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/horamensajecotizacion"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Horamen" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView></LinearLayout>
```

Y este es el Activity del Chat

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ChatActivity">

<include layout="@layout/toolbarchat"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarchat" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:id="@+id/imagenperfil"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/nombreperfil"
            android:text="Loperso"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/mensajes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="459dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/escribir"
            android:hint="Meen, el mensaje"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imagenbuscar"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/enviar"
            android:hint="Envia men"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout></android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: estas configurando 2 veces el recyclerView (mensajes.setAdapter(adaptador) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad estas definiendo la variable

```
private mensajeAdaptador adaptador;
```

y dentro de `onCreate()` estas configurando este `Adapter` pero sin inicializarlo;
pero llamas posteriormente el método `añadirMensaje()` que es quien inicializaría el `Adapter` y quien configura este `Adapter` a tu `RecyclerView`.

Te sugiero simplemente eliminar la linea  `mensajes.setAdapter(adaptador)` que se encuentra dentro de `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    ...
    //mensajes.setAdapter(adaptador); //*Eliminar linea.
    ...
    ...
    añadirMensaje();
    ...
    ...
    }
```

Posteriormente en el método `añadirMensaje()` inicializa correctamente el `Adapter`:

```
public void añadirMensaje() {
    //mensajeAdaptador ms = new mensajeAdaptador(mensajesArray, this);
    mensajeAdaptador adaptador = new mensajeAdaptador(mensajesArray, this);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, OrientationHelper.VERTICAL, false);
    mensajes.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mensajes.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mensajes.setAdapter(adaptador);
}
```

Comment: Si, definitivamente era eso. Estaba cambiando el adaptador porque no usaba el ViewType y se me olvido quitar eso. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Excelente, me da gusto solucionaste el problema, saludos! @Loperso

Answer (score 0):

Intenta reemplazando la primer linea de tu método añadirMensaje() por

```
adaptador = new mensajeAdaptador(mensajesArray, this);
```

Me parece que estás declarando la variable **adaptador** en tu clase **ChatActivity** pero no la inicializas.

Comment: Si, era eso. Muchas gracias.