# ¿Por qué mi aplicación de android se muestra en algunos dispositivos y en otros no?

Tags: java, android, sdk

Estoy realizando una aplicación android la cual se conecta a una base de datos a través de un web services. Cuando mando traer los datos de la base de datos, estos se muestran en mi android 4.4.2 (teléfono físico) pero, no se muestran en mi android 9 ni 10 (teléfono físico) ni tampoco en el emulador que tiene un android 10.

La configuración en el grade.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ejemplo.codigo.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        maxSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}
```

Agrego como tengo configurado el reciclerView y el adapter:

```
List<Product> productList;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

//Dentro del onCreate    
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
productList = new ArrayList<>();
loadproduct();
//Termina el onCreate

private void loadproduct() {
   StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_product, new Response.Listener<String>() {
      @Override
          public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
               JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        productList.add(new Product(
                                product.getString("nombre"),
                                product.getString("descripcion"),
                                product.getString("imagen")
                        ));
                    }

                    ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(getApplicationContext(), productList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplication(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Agrego como lo configuré de acuerdo a la respuesta. Lo agrego porque aún sigue sin mostrarme los datos en android 9 y 10 tanto en teléfono físico como en emulador pero, en android 4.4.2 (teléfono físico) sí me muestra los datos.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ArrayList<Product> productList;

//Dentro del onCreate
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

productList = new ArrayList<>();

loadProduct();
//Termina onCreate

private void loadProduct() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_product, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        productList.add(new Product(
                                product.getString("nombre"),
                                product.getString("descripcion"),
                                product.getString("imagen")
                        ));
                    }

                    ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(getApplicationContext(), productList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplication(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Verifica el log primeramente con el emulador de Android 10 para poder ver que error te sale. ;)

Comment: Gracias por responder Israel-ICM Ya verifiqué el log y muestra lo siguiente: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout --------                                  Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without... ----------                                                  D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

Comment: El problema no creo sea tu configuraciòn, agrega como configuras el recyclerView y el adapter para cargar los datos.

Comment: Hola Elenasys♦ gracias por responder. En seguida agrego como tengo configurado el recyclerView y el adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo a la configuraciòn que muestras tu aplicaciòn debe funcionar desde Android 4.1 (API nivel 16) hasta Android 10 (API nivel 29).

Pero el problema que indicas

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

se debe generalmente a que no configuras un adaptador sin inicializarlo o configuras uno vacio, no estas definiendo un layoutManager a tu RecyclerView, o simplemente el listado de datos que recibe tu Adapter no tiene informaciòn.

```
//Inicializa layoutManager
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
//Inicializa Adapter
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), datos);
//Configura Adapter
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Revisa:

[Me sale el error RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout cuando trato de cargar un RecyclerView](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/198318/me-sale-el-error-recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout-cuando-trato)

[Siempre obtengo "E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout" cuando hago el intent para acceder al activity en cuestión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/305562/siempre-obtengo-e-recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout-cuando-ha/305815#305815)

Comment: Elenasys♦ Ya he agregado como tengo la configuración del recyclerView y el adapter. Veo que me falta el layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL).

Comment: Es importante, de otra forma no se mostrará tu recyclerview @kayvos

Comment: Elenasys♦ Modifiqué un poco el código de acuerdo a la respuesta que me proporcionaste pero, sigue sin mostrarme los datos en android 9 y 10 (teléfono físico y emulador) pero, si me los muestra en android 4.4.2 (teléfono físico). Soy nueva en android, disculpa las molestias :(

Answer (score 0):

No había tenido tiempo de comentarles que los datos que mando a traer del web services ya se muestran en todos los dispositivos.

Después de verificar y modificar un poco el código de acuerdo a la respuesta de Jorgesys♦, en el logcat me marcaba lo siguiente:

Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted

Así que realicé lo que está en la respuesta a está pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

```
//network_security_config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
        <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
        <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">modificar</domain>
        </domain-config>
    </network-security-config>




//Manifest
<application
..
..
..
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
..
..
..
</application>
```