# No adapter attached; skipping layout en kotllin

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-recyclerview

Estoy trabajando en una app, esta tiene como fin el poder listar un registro desde firebase, para esto utilizo un *RecyclerView*, todo bien, cuando traigo los datos y muestro por consola todo bien, pero el problema esta al tratar de mostrar en el *RecyclerView*, verán, con el simple echo de agregar un nuevo *RecyclerView* a mi interfaz y compilar, me genera este error_

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

No tengo código, no tengo nada, solamente agrego el *RecyclerView* y en consola veo ese error, y si trato de agregar un código que pueda mostrar una lista aleatoria, no me deja por el error comentado anterior mente, **y si quito el *RecyclerView* el error desaparece**, literalmente me esta poniendo problemas el simple echo de agregar un *RecyclerView*, el único código que agrego es este:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Ya no hago mas nada y pum muestra el error mencionado.

¿Alguien me puede decir el por que de esto tan extraño?

Comment: Es importante agregues el código de como estas inicializando tu RecyclerView, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema

> RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Se debe principalmente a 3 cosas

No defines la cantidad de elementos que se mostraran en tu Adapter, no los defines al inicializar el adapter o simplemente es un array vacío.

---

Dentro de tu adapter debes definir en `getItemCount()` la cantidad de elementos a mostrar :

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (elementos != null){
      return elementos.size();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Configuras un adaptador sin inicializarlo o configuras uno vacio, no estas definiendo un layoutManager a tu RecyclerView

```
//Inicializa layoutManager
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
//Inicializa Adapter
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), datos);
//Configura Adapter
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

revisa:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/396101/95